# permuted inverse matrix multiplication

Tags: matrices, inverse, matrix-calculus

consider the following case where T is any matrix and P is the permutation matrix
we know that:
$T*T^-1=I$
now lets permute the matrix and multiply it with the inverse
$T*P*T^-1$
is there any way to calculate this multiplication faster? the fact that we know the T matrix (or T^-1) is permuted will help?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You suppose that $T^{-1}$ is known? What do you mean exactly by "computing the multiplication faster"?

Comment: yes, T^-1 is known. knowing the fact we know that T or T^-1 is permuted can we calculate T*P*T^-1 will less number of multiplication and addition or not?